# Google Cast is="google-cast-button" Not Loading When Inside Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to add Google Cast to my music app. It works properly when I include the button and the script in the index.html file. However, when I move the button to a component, it no longer registers the button. I have tried adding this code to the components constructor as a way of delaying the load time of the cast library but it still doesn't register:

```
let script = window['document'].createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1');
window['document'].body.appendChild(script);
```

I copied this idea from the source of this npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-cast

Any idea on how I can get the is="google-cast-button" to register late in the load process?

Comment: ng-cast doesn't even use this attribute. Are you sure it's necessary to achieve the behavior you want?

Comment: if I want to load the button inside a component, I have to figure out how to pull something off like this

Comment: I don't think you need the attribute, though. The JavaScript cast framework allows you to hook the button up to Chrome's casting functionality yourself. It's just a bit more work. Look at the rest of ng-cast's source code. Or... maybe just use ng-cast instead of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 3):

The most robust solution in my opinion is to add `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` to either your app.module.ts or feature.module.ts. By doing so, you can place the chrome cast button in your app with `<google-cast-launcher></google-cast-launcher>`, which is far more stable than messing with the DOM manually within your component.

Answer (score 1):

I found this with react.js - if the button is created via innerHTML, then the 'is=' scripts of the web component won't run.  The only way to get the scripts to run on a dynamically created button is to use the document.createElement syntax.  This may mean digging in to angular to figure out how to create one that way. In react, it means waiting for componentDidMount and inserting the element into the DOM that way.

So not a BIG help, but maybe a hint of what to try next (granted it has been a few months).